# Identify hosts that are serving specific metric on Shodan

Tags: webserver, metrics, host-discovery, shodan

Using things like Shodan and Zoomeye we can find tens of thousands of exposed Prometheus endpoints with queries like `service:prometheus` `port:9090` etc..
Now let's say we know that there are entities on the internet that are serving a specific `some_metric` on `/metrics` endpoint for some Prometheus to scape.

```
# HELP some_metric Description of the target metric.
# TYPE some_metric gauge
some_metric 123456789
```

How do we get a list of hosts that are serving this specific metric? Using some search engine or other ways.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a Python script...

Comment: Using a tool such as nmap, zmap or masscan, targeting specific IP address ranges, or the Internet as a whole.